# Remote access using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, cisco, cisco-ios

I'm using a python script to access to cisco switch using SSH or telnet .. I'm using module pexpect .. the connection done. My problem that, when I want to show all the configuration using

> telconn.sendline("sh run " + "\r")

I can't see all the configuration cuz I face a problem with --more--. So how I can avoid this and what I can do to see all the configuration

Comment: plz, any update. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `terminal length 0` command first. That will disable pagination that is enabled on the router by default.